# problem to call a unity mehtod when a bool condition is True

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback

I have a problem with calling the EndGame method when the necessary condition is triggered, in my unity quartets card game.

The EndGane method should be call CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty. However, when all in my project all playerHands are empty, I get this error when I try to call the EndGamemethod:

```
Assets\Scripts\Managers\CardManager.cs(172,13): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'
```

I note that this problem occurs only with this line of code is introduce at the end of DistributeCards()

```
if (CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty())
    {
        playerManager.GetComponent<MainGameManager>().EndGame(Players);
    }
```

I assume this if statement is the problematic code since:

1. If I replace the above if statement with [ICODE]CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpt();[/ICODE] the  CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty runs correctly and show up the right log.
2. My project functions as expected currently, i.e. all variables refer and communicate as needed.
3. The called method isn't the problem, the EndGame method functions otherwise and when another method is called the same error persists.

since the syntax of the if statement seems correct.... I'm locked in a vision that nothing can be wrong... which as my game reality shows is wrong, there error is there.

Any idea as to how to overcome this problem will be highly appreciated.

The relevant codes:

CardManager.cs:

```
public class CardManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cardPrefab;
    public Transform deck;

    private List<Card> deckCards;
    public List<Player> Players = new List<Player>();
    public Transform undistributedCardsParent; // Reference to the parent transform for undistributed cards

    public PlayerManager playerManager; // Reference to the PlayerManager


    public bool IsCardDistributionComplete
    {
        get { return isCardDistributionComplete; }
    }

    // Method to initialize cards with loaded data to the Deck
    public void InitializeCards(List<CardData> cardDataList)
    {
        // Convert CardData to Card objects and store them in the deckCards list
        deckCards = new List<Card>();
        foreach (CardData cardData in cardDataList)
        {
            Card card = new Card();
            //other attributes
        }

        // Cards are initialized, you can proceed with further logic here
        ShuffleDeck();
        DistributeCards();
    }

    private void ShuffleDeck()
    {
        
    }

    public void DistributeCards()
    {   
        
        int cardsToDistribute = 4; 
        
        //distribution logic here

        // Instantiate undistributed cards on the deck
        for (int i = 0; i < deckCards.Count; i++)
        {
            Card card = deckCards[i];
            Vector3 positionOffset = new Vector3(i * 1.2f, i * 1.2f, -i * 1f); // Adjust the position offset for each card
        }

        isCardDistributionComplete = true;

        // After distributing cards, check if all player hands are empty and trigger game end if needed
        CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty();
        
        //here I tried both version, with Line n.1 and without, tje error appeared in both cases
        /*j1. playerManager.GetComponent<EndGameTest>().EndingGame(Players);
        if (CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty())
        {
            playerManager.GetComponent<EndGameTest>().EndingGame(Players);
        }*/    
    }

    // Add this method to check if all players' hands are empty
    public void CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty()
    {
        bool allHandsEmpty = true;

        foreach (Player player in Players)
        {
            if (!player.IsHandEmpty())
            {
                allHandsEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allHandsEmpty)
        {
            // All player hands are empty, trigger game end logic
            Debug.Log("All player hands are empty. Game should end.");
        }
    }

    //other methods
}
```

EndGameTest.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EndGameTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image endScreenBackground;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void EndingGame(List<Player> players)
    {
        Debug.Log("Game has ended!");

        endScreenBackground.gameObject.SetActive(true); // Activate the background
    }

}
```

In case it is relevant:

Card.cs:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Card : IComparable<Card>
{
    public string rank;
    public string cardName;
    public string hint;
    public string level;
    public Sprite illustration;
    public GameObject gameObject;

    public int CompareTo(Card other)
    {
        // Sort by rank alphabetically
        return String.Compare(rank, other.rank, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

CardController.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class CardController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text cardRankText;
    public TMP_Text cardNameText;
    public TMP_Text cardHintText;
    public TMP_Text cardLevelText;
    public Image cardIllustrationImage;

    public void SetCardData(Card card)
    {
        cardRankText.text = "Rank: " + card.rank;
        cardNameText.text = "Name: " + card.cardName;
        cardHintText.text = "Hint: " + card.hint;
        cardLevelText.text = "Level: " + card.level;
        cardIllustrationImage.sprite = card.illustration;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your return type from checkallplayerhandsempty is void. It is therefore not going to help you make a bool decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is, that `CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty` cannot be used as an if-condition since it does not return a bool.

Instead of `public void CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty()` it should be `public bool CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty()` and return allHandsEmpty in a final statement.

```
public bool CheckAllPlayerHandsEmpty()
    {
        bool allHandsEmpty = true;

        foreach (Player player in Players)
        {
            if (!player.IsHandEmpty())
            {
                allHandsEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (allHandsEmpty)
        {
            // All player hands are empty, trigger game end logic
            Debug.Log("All player hands are empty. Game should end.");
        }

        return allHandsEmpty;
    }
```

Comment: Great, that's did the magit. Thanks for taking the time to help.